# How to convert an array of character codes to string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this function:

```
function ungarble(garble){
  var s = "";
  for( var i = 0; i < garble.length; i++ ) {
    s += String.fromCharCode(garble[i]);
  }
  return s;
}
```

It takes in an array of charCodes, then returns a string those charCodes represented.

Does native Javascript have a function that does this?

Note: This is for reading messages returned by `child_process.spawn`.

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(...garble)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) already accepts any amount of arguments to convert to a string, so you can simply use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to give it an array:

```js
var chars = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100];

var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, chars);

console.log(str);
```

or using [ES6 spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
var chars = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100];

var str = String.fromCharCode(...chars);

console.log(str);
```

Comment: I think this will not work if `chars` has more than 65536 elements because that's the limit for the number of arguments that can be passed to a function.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply?ref=yuji.page#using_apply_to_append_an_array_to_another

Answer (score 0):

How about the reduce function?

```
 function ungarble(chars) {
    return chars.reduce(function(allString, char) {
        return allString += String.fromCharCode(char);
    }, '');
}

let result = ungarble([65, 66, 67]);

console.log(result) // "ABC"
```